# Universal type for any yield type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, yield

Trying to have a system able to store any kind of yield instructions

```
YieldInstruction m_yield;

void SetInstruction()
{
    switch(condition)
    {
        case UseWait:
            m_yield = new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            break;
        case UseWaitUntil:
            m_yield = new WaitUntil(() => flag == true); // Cannot cast here
    }
}
```

Changing the type to IEnumerator puts the problem on the first one.
CustomeYieldInstruction is not doing either.

I can't put my finger on what is the relation between YieldInstruction and CustomYieldInstruction. Despite the names, one is its own base type and the latter is IEnumerator.

I'm also confused since the two methods can yield in a IEnumerator method but won't cast into it if done as I am trying.

```
public sealed class WaitForSeconds : YieldInstruction{ /* ** */ }
public class YieldInstruction { }

public sealed class WaitUntil : CustomYieldInstruction { /* ** */}
public abstract class CustomYieldInstruction : IEnumerator { /* ** */ }
```

and I can do :

```
public IEnumerator Sequence()
{
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f),
     yield return new WaitUntil(()=> condition == true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to [Menyus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66635709/7111561)

I'd say using `object` is a bit too dirty for my taste.

But you could simply build a wrapper `IEnumerator` for those types that do not implement it themselves (like anything based on the internal times):

```c#
private IEnumerator WaitForYieldInstruction(YieldInstruction instruction)
{
    yield return instruction;
}
```

and then use

```c#
IEnumerator m_yield;

void SetInstruction()
{
    switch(condition)
    {
        case UseWait:
            m_yield = WaitForYieldInstruction(new WaitForSeconds(1f));
            break;
        case UseWaitUntil:
            m_yield = new WaitUntil(() => flag); 
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed i would say avoid `Object`.  Elegant solution. I'm currently writing a wrapper class for YieldInstructions but this one i like better i might aint even post it.

Comment: We do have some "ugly" wrapper of our own called Yield that I wish to avoid using. I'd rather have that one since it does not create a new type. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`YieldInstruction` gets special treatments from Unity's internal system. If you just look at `WaitUntil` it needs no special treatments from the internal Engine(C/C++) since it just expects a C# predicate. On the other hand `WaitForSeconds`, `WaitForEndOfFrame` ofc needs some special treatments. In the former one it needs the internal timer, in the latter one the coroutine scheduler have to make a special interrupt just at the end of frame which is kinda impossible with just the managed scripting side.

Also do not forget you can yield anything! null also does not implement `IEnumerator` nor `string` etc..

When you call `StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine);` you are basically registering the method into Unity's coroutine scheduler and it is implemented in C/C++.

Back to your original question. Luckily in C# every class inherits from `System.Object` so they can have a base class.